# Java ArrayList for-loop lcv thought to be an object, not an int

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to make an array with a sequence of variable length, so I decided to use an ArrayList.

Since I want to find the sum of the sequence of numbers, I tried to use the ArrayList.get(int index) method to get the value of an element in the ArrayList, but NetBeans is complaining at me about `incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to int` for the following code:

```
int seqLen = sequence.size(); // number of elements in ArrayList sequence
int seqSum = 0; // sum of all elements in the sequence
for(int i = 0; i <= seqLen; i++) {
   int seqPart = sequence.get(i);
   seqSum+= seqPart;
}
```

Specifically, the line `int seqPart = sequence.get(i);`

I'm not sure why it thinks that `i` is an `object` and not an `int`, and this block of code is crucial for the program to work.

Basically, what am I doing wrong here, I've gone over the JavaDoc for ArrayList a couple times now, but I still haven't figured out what's wrong.

Comment: what are the values that you're keeping in this ArrayList?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at [the JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get(int)), you'll notice that `get` returns an `E`.  If you don't define what that E is, it'll default to Object.  An Object can't be assigned to an int.  Define your arraylist like this:

```
List<Integer> sequence = new ArrayList<>();
```

This says, "I'm going to fill this ArrayList with Integers".  That way when you call `get()` it'll return an `Integer` instead of an `Object`.

This part is a little more advanced and not super important so don't worry if it goes over your head: The reason you can assign that `Integer` to an `int` is because of a concept called [Auto unboxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html).